# Trigger before login

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to create an observer that call a function right before the user logs in. I have Googled the problem, but with no good results.

The problem is:
User writes login data, hits enter, my function is called to make some checks and then continue or break; the login process.

I didn't find any event or observer.

Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: Wow all these answers by the regulars but no up votes!?!??!?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_loginpost` and `controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_createpost`.Those events are every good for when customer is `loggin via`  using urls **customer/account/loginpost/** and  customer register via url **customer/account/createpost**.

As Sander say,magento is always triggers below events on

```
'controller_action_predispatch'
'controller_action_predispatch_' . $this->getRequest()->getRouteName()
'controller_action_predispatch_' . $this->getFullActionName()
```

then ,if you loggin via `custom route` then you need to define `observer code` at `config.xml` code.Suppose ,you have **loggin using Customer router** `mycustomroute/mycustom/myaction`  and `guess` that route class is `MynameSpace_MycustomCntoller_Myaction`.The event for this controller is
`controller_action_predispatch_mycustomroute_mycustom_myaction` and you `observer` code look like

```
<events>
      <controller_action_predispatch_mycustomroute_mycustom_myaction>
         <observers>
        <trigger_before_login>
         <class>YourModuleModeltype/observer code</class>
        <method>controllerActionPredispatchCustomerAccountLoginPost</method>
        </trigger_before_login>
        </observers>
      </controller_action_predispatch_mycustomroute_mycustom_myaction>     
  </events>
```

**Then every login post url you  need define a new observer code:**

### Alternative idea:

I have an idea which may be good.

Magento is fire the `customer_login` event on `customer loggin`.
On class `Mage_Customer_Model_Session` at function `setCustomerAsLoggedIn`

```
   public function setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer)
    {
        $this->setCustomer($customer);
        $this->renewSession();
        Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_login', array('customer'=>$customer));
        return $this;
    }
```

On this function,using `setCustomer()` magento is `set Customer` and `create renew session` for Customer.

If i have define `a new event before`  **$this->setCustomer($customer);**.Then using this `custom define event Trigger before login`

Just:

```
public function setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer)
{
/* my Custom event */
    Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_before_login', array('customer'=>$customer));
    $this->setCustomer($customer);
    $this->renewSession();
    Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_login', array('customer'=>$customer));
    return $this;
}
```

Then using  `customer_before_login` you can fire event.

Observer code at `config.xml` look like:

```
<events>
      <customer_before_login>
         <observers>
        <trigger_before_login>
         <class>YourModuleModeltype/observer code</class>
        <method>controllerActionPredispatchCustomerAccountLoginPost</method>
        </trigger_before_login>
        </observers>
      </customer_before_login>     
    </events>
```

Comment: yes, this is the solution! thanks a lot and sorry for the delay in response.

Answer (score 4):

When a request is made one of the methods that is always triggered is `preDispatch` in the class `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action`.

This method provides a couple of events

- '`controller_action_predispatch`'
- '`controller_action_predispatch_`' . `$this->getRequest()->getRouteName()`
- '`controller_action_predispatch_`' . `$this->getFullActionName()`

Which, for the customer login post URL translates for the last two to

- `controller_action_predispatch_customer`
- `controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_loginPost`

With that you could add the following observer

```
[...]
    <events>
      <controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_loginPost>
         <observers><[namespace]_[module]_controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_loginPost>
            <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>controllerActionPredispatchCustomerAccountLoginPost</method></[namespace]_[module]_controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_loginPost>
        </observers>
      </controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_loginPost>     
    </events>
[...]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use these

- `controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_loginpost` for when the user logs in using the login form and when he logs in from the checkout process
- `controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_createpost` if you don't use account validation and the user is logged in when creating an account.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to write a event observer for this :

Register the event for customer login in your module's `config.xml`

```
<customer_login>
<observers>
    <yourobservername>
        <type>model</type>
        <class>yourmodule/path_to_class</class>
        <method>customerLogin</method>
    </yourobservername>
</observers>
```

Your observer class would look like this:

```
class YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Observer
{
    public function customerLogin($observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
        // your checking code here
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is how to write the observer. I think the OP is asking what event to observe.

Comment: So you do know how to vote

Comment: @Marius couldn't he just dispatch his own event?

Comment: @easymoden00b. Not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: @Marius Mage::dispatchEvent('my_event_name', $data);, could go anywhere really.