# How to deactivate the user automatically after 1 day Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, customer

How to deactivate or inactive the user/customer automatically after one day in our website, Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't deactivate users, you can only delete them and yes, it is possible to delete them one day after the account is created.

**Edit: THE CODE**

Well, like I said, you either run the script yourself at least once every day or setup a cron job (use AOE Scheduler Extension if you can't access your server's settings), either way, here is the PHP code you need to run to delete the users that registered more than 24 hours ago.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London'); /*Replace "Europe/London" by your timezone according to http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php*/
$currDate = "".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."";
$users = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
foreach($users as $user){
    $createdAt = $user->getCreatedAtTimestamp();
    $createdAt = "".date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$createdAt)."";
    $diff = ((strtotime($currDate) - strtotime($createdAt)) / 3600);
    if($diff > 24){
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($user->getId());
        Mage::register('isSecureArea', TRUE);
        $customer->delete();
        Mage::unregister('isSecureArea');
    }
}
```

I tested it myself and it is fully functional, so, let me know!

Comment: I think we can deactivate user as i found is_active field in database. Anyways, could you please tell how to delete them automatically after 1 day or specific interval?

Comment: @MaceLong, you are correct, there is a field in the database "is_active" but Magento's core does not check it when a customer is logging in or anything, this field just like sits there, Magento does not use it. Give me a few moments and I will post the code here! Do you know how to set up a cron job?

Comment: no, I'm sorry,but cron job is default setup.

Comment: @MaceLong, in that case you two ways to do it, either you run the PHP script everyday yourself or you install an extension that allows you to create a cron job from Magento's backend

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul, I got the idea how to proceed with the code.

Comment: @MaceLong you welcome, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a `Customer Since` customer attribute, which keeps record of customer created date.

You should create an observer for `controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_loginpost` and `controller_action_predispatch_customer_account_createpost` events.
Place a code to check if customer is created before 1 day (24 hours or more) using `Customer Since` attribute and prevent to be logged in. No need to deactive OR delete customer.

You can use `preDispatch` method also. For more, check [Trigger before login](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54780/trigger-before-login)

If you really want to delete a customer, use:

```
$id = 10;//replace with your desired customer id
//or load by Email
//$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->loadByEmail($email);
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);
$customer->delete();
```

For deactivate customer, use :

```
$id = 10;//replace with your desired customer id
//or load by Email
//$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->loadByEmail($email);
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);
$customer->setIsActive(0);
$customer->save();
```

Comment: $customer->setIsActive(0);
$customer->save();

didn't work..have you tested it?

Comment: For this you need to override the `Mage_Customer_AccountController` to check the value of this field inside `loginPostAction()` OR `preDispatch` as Magento is not checking the value of  `is_active` attribute